# Logically deducing inverse square law (physics)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity, physics

Consider a hollow spherical charge with density $\rho'$ **continuously varying** only with respect to distance from the center $O$.

[image]

$V'=$ yellow volume

$k \in \mathbb {R}$

$\forall$ point $P$ **inside** the hollow sphere, electric field is zero. Now I have to prove the following two theorems:

$(1)$ **Given:** $\vec{E}_P=\displaystyle\int_{V'}\rho'\ f(r) (\hat{r})=0$.

**To prove:** $f(r)=\dfrac{k}{r^2}$

$(2)$ **Given:** $\vec{E}_P=\displaystyle\int_{V'}\rho'\ \vec{f}(r) = 0$.

**To prove:** $\vec{f}(r)=\dfrac{k\ \hat{r}}{r^2}$

> Can we prove these two theorems? If yes for any, please help me to prove it.

Comment: These are clearly wrong as stated.  If the given $f$ or $\vec{f}$ works then so does $k f$ or $k \vec{f}$ for any constant scalar $k$.

Comment: Please consider that $\vec{E}_P$ is electric field inside the hollow sphere which is zero.

Comment: Please have a look at my edited question.

Comment: After reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem), is there any more proof guidance you'd like?

Comment: @J.G. The converse theorem (which I think is closest to this question) is mentioned on that page but I don't see much in the way of hints toward a proof. In addition, this question does not say anything about the field outside the sphere, so it is not even the same as the converse theorem on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Please note that the second theorem is not the converse of shell theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's convenient to work with a potential $u$ so $\vec{f}=-\nabla u$. For (2) to hold for arbitrary spherically symmetric $\rho$, it must in particular work when $\rho=m\delta^3(r-a^\prime)$, viz.$$\partial_p\int_0^\pi d\theta\sin\theta u\left(\sqrt{p^2+a^{\prime2}-2pa^\prime\cos\theta}\right)=0.$$Substitute $r^2=p^2+a^{\prime2}-2pa^\prime\cos\theta$ so$$\partial_p\int_{a^\prime-p}^{a^\prime+p}\frac{rdr}{p}u(r)=0.$$But then$$\int_{a^\prime-p}^{a^\prime+p}ru(r)dr\propto p\implies(a^\prime+p)u(a^\prime+p)+(a^\prime-p)u(a^\prime-p)=\operatorname{constant},$$and the case $a^\prime=0$ shows this constant is $0$, provided we identify a radius of $-p$ with one of $p$. So$$u(r)\propto\frac1r\implies \vec{f}(r)\propto\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}.$$The treatment of (1) is similar.

Comment: How can we know a priori or a posteriori that $\vec{f}=-\nabla u$?

Comment: @Joe Show [with this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula) that a spherically symmetric $\vec{f}$ has $\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{f}=\vec{0}$.

Comment: I know it is given that $\rho'$ is spherically symmetrical around $O$. From this how shall we deduce that $\vec{f}$ is spherically symmetric, i.e. $\vec{f}$ points in the direction from center to source point. Or are we just assuming it?

Comment: @Joe Technically, the behaviour of $\vec{f}$ gets to something different, namely how a point charge would exert force on a test charge. That such a force would be radial is technically a physical assumption (but honestly, what else would it be?) In fact, it's equivalent to that force conserving the angular momentum.

Comment: May I know what $\partial_p$ means?

Comment: @Joe It's shorthand for $\frac{\partial}{\partial p}$.

Comment: Why is there only one integral (with respect to $\theta$) when we are dealing with volume charge of hollow sphere?

Comment: @Joe The Dirac delta dealt with $r$, & $\int d\phi$ factors out.

Comment: @Joe I differentiated the integral.